# Reading SAS Transport Files in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, r, sas

Is there a way to read SAS Transport Files in an ASP.NET application? I see that "R" has a library to do this (read.xport(file)) but it's not clear to me I can run "R" on a system where I can not install packages (think shared hosting). Any post processing of data will be done by my application so I just need to "read" these files.

Comment: The transport file format is published, so perhaps you can use the documentation? http://support.sas.com/techsup/technote/ts140.html

Comment: @Joe There's some pretty interesting code/comments in that link.  Just goes to show how much goes on under the hood that we take for granted..

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is from [this blog post](http://savian.blogspot.com/2011/02/sas-transport-files-and-net.html) from Alan Churchill.  He's probably the expert in SAS - .NET interoperability, so I recommend looking around his site for further information if needed.

> Download and install the SAS Universal Viewer from the SAS support
>   site
>
> Create a new project in Visual Studio Add a reference from the
>   SAS Universal Viewer install files to the following 2 dlls
>
> SAS.UV.Transport    SAS.UV.Utility
>
> Use the following C# code (adapt as
>   needed):
>
> TransportFile tf = new TransportFile(@"x:\temp\sample.xpt");
>   var x = tf.Datasets;
>
> Your dataset will be in variable x.

Comment: I saw that one earlier and tried it. Didn't work. The dll's have other dependencies.